# Why Android UDP server does not receive packets after delay

Tags: android, udp

I try to work with the UDP server code below on my device.
Strange behavour.
If I send first packet to device it does not receive it,
staying on "ds.receive(dp);".
Then the program receives next packets okay,
if I send them with interval less than about 20 seconds.
But after sending delay about 20 seconds it stops receiving again.
Then again it receives the next packets

```
    public class UDP_Server {
    private AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> async;
    int udp;
    private boolean serverActive = true;
    InetAddress inetAddress;

    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    public void runUdpServer(int udp1) {
        udp=udp1;
        async = new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>() {
            @Override
            protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
                byte[] lMsg = new byte[2048];
                DatagramPacket dp = new DatagramPacket(lMsg, lMsg.length);
                DatagramSocket ds = null;
                My.saveLog("start receive ");

                try {
                    ds = new DatagramSocket(udp);

                    while (serverActive) {
                        My.saveLog("start receive2 ");
                        ds.setSoTimeout(0);
                        ds.receive(dp);
                        My.saveLog("start receive3");

                        ...

                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } finally {
                    if (ds != null) {
                        ds.close();
                    }
                }

                return null;
            }
        };

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 11) async.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR);
        else async.execute();
    }

    public void stop_UDP_Server() {
        serverActive = false;
    }
}
```

Any ideas please!

UPDATE: I ran client, written on .NET C# from Win7.
When I  run the similar UDP Linux client from VMWare with linux image on Win7
it works okay. Problem is in client...
Miracles...

Comment: Is this behavior consistent or can it be due to random package loss?

Comment: I always see this behaviour. My phone does not go to sleep mode. I send UDP packets from another device. I mean I send manually one packet per a few seconds

Comment: Are you sure your sending solution is not grouping packets?

Comment: I send packets manually with a few seconds interval. Certainly problem is in client. I used c# app, the same Linux app client is okay. Please take a look to my update above. Thanks!